# Duplicate Symbol error xcode iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am getting duplicate error in my xcode while build and run

I have two files file1.m and file2.m both use same variable and function names

file1.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface file1 : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UILabel *result;   

}

-(IBAction)home;

@end
```

file1.m

```
#include<file1.h>
@implementation file1
int count = 0;
int arr[2][2];
```

file2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface file2 : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UILabel *result;   

}

-(IBAction)home;

@end
```

file2.m

```
#include<file2.h>
@implementation file2
int count = 0;
int arr[2][2];
```

When Build and run it gives me error duplicate symbol "count" in file1.o and file2. o
if I change their names to count1 and count2 I will not get any error.

In both file1.m and file2.m I am trying to make global variables.

Is there any way by which I can use same names of variable and functions in both the files

Comment: can you post the .h too?

Comment: Are you defining global variables here? If so, did you intend doing so? Please provide a bit more code.

Comment: I posted a new code. @HermannKlecker yes, I am trying to define global variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make them `static`:

```
static int count = 0;
static int arr[2][2];
```

Note that they'll refer to *different* variables.  If you want to them to refer to the *same* variables, leave it the way you have it in one file and declare them `extern` in the other file:

```
extern int count;
extern int arr[2][2];
```

It's common to put those `extern` declarations in a common header.

Comment: file1.m variables and file2.m variables has nothing to do with each other I want them to be seperated

Comment: Then `static` is the way to go.

Comment: and what about if I have same function name in both .m files

Comment: Well, since the "functions" you appear to be talking about are actually instance methods, that won't be a problem.  You could have two `static` functions with the same name just as in my example, though.  It's a bit weird, but it's been known to happen.

Comment: In file1.m I used int count = 0; and in file2.m static int count = 0; Thanks it worked

Comment: You should make both of them `static`.

Comment: Thanks I made both of them static